# Store return value of function in jquery variable

Tags: javascript

My jquery function looks following ,

```
var d= rdldb.restaurantbooking.where('date').equals("2015-09-30").toArray(jstr); 
//jstr is a function 

function jstr(v){ return  JSON.stringify(v);  }

//console.log(JSON.stringify) shows my desired output 
//and the same output need to be shown when i display variable d.

/*  output of jstr() function is
   [{"booking_id":-2,"restbooking_id":"RDOFFL-2",,"bstate":"on"}    
   ,{"booking_id":"18487","restbooking_id":"RDOFFL-3","bstate":"on"},   
   {"booking_id":"18488","restbooking_id":"Id9","bstate":"on"}, 
   {"booking_id":"18489","restbooking_id":"d","bstate":"on"}]
*/

console.log(d); //Output is empty .
```

`jstr()` function is not returning value to variable d.

What is the solution to get my desired output in first function?

Comment: FYI there is no jQuery code here. Secondly, What is the outputs of `where()`, `equals()` and `toArray()`?

Comment: some browsers don't display objects in the console unless the debugger is also open, try F12 in firefox instead of the browser console only

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan.  This is indexedDB function implemented in jquery

Comment: jquery .toArray() doesn't want arguments. you could try `var d = JSON.stringify( rdldb.restaurantbooking.where('date').equals("2015-09-30") );`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio it shows all the values. i could do parse json data. thanks

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio . either toArray() , each function i have to use in my scanario . For your ref:    https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/WhereClause.

Comment: @Arockiaraj too loong to write in a comment. I posted an answer, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

array "x" will contain a stringified version of your JSON array d.

```
var d = rdldb.restaurantbooking.where('date').equals("2015-09-30").toArray();

var x = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < d.length; i++) {
    x.push( JSON.stringify( d[i] ) );
}
```

Comment: in toArray() there should be a call back function like given in my question . So from call back value should be returned to d.